# How to hide kendo grid command custom tooltip

Tags: kendo-grid

Someone has posted this solution earlier - jsfiddle.net/QM3p7 - which helped me a lot and would like to know how I can hide the tooltip after the user clicks on the button.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to hide the tooltip with the following statement - $("#grid").data("kendoTooltip").hide();